# How to resize the axes or size of a figure?

Tags: matlab, figure

I have a problem.
My figure is unclear in the magnitude of some lines, as in my attachment-fig.
My code is as below:

```
figure(1)
plot(t,100*yt)
plot(zeros(length,1),'k--'); xlim([0 irflength]);set(gca,'XTick',[4:4:irflength],'FontSize',12);
title('Out','FontSize',16);xlim([t(1) t(end)]);set(gca,'XTick',t(4:4:end),'FontSize',12);
ylabel('Percent','FontSize',12)
```

[image]

Comment: What language is that? What program are you using for the plot?

Comment: Matlab. Is it not a forum for matlab?

Comment: Not matlab exclusive. Perhaps you should [take the Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need the `axis` function. For instance `axis([0 , irflength , 1 , 1.5])`